# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to BufferedImage

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bufferedimage

It's being really weird, the error is at `textures[x]`.

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to BufferedImage
```

What is wrong with the code here?

```
static BufferedImage textures[][] = new BufferedImage[20][20];

public static void loadTextures()
{
    try 
    {
        //Loads The Image
        BufferedImage textures = ImageIO.read(new URL("textures.png"));

        for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x += 1)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 1280; y += 1)
            {
                textures[x][y] = textures.getSubimage(x*64, y*64, 64, 64);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the name that you gave to your array for the image that you are planning to parcel into individual elements. You should give it a different name to make it work:

```
BufferedImage fullImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("textures.png"));

for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x += 1) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 1280; y += 1) {
        textures[x][y] = fullImage.getSubimage(x*64, y*64, 64, 64);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new variable called `textures` here:

```
BufferedImage textures = ImageIO.read(new URL("textures.png"));
```

which is not a 2D array like the `static` variable. `textures[x][y]` in the `for`-loop is referencing *this* variable, which explains the error. Rename one of them to solve the problem.

By the way this is called *[variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an ambiguity going on.. change the local variable name from `BufferedImage textures` to `BufferedImage texture`