# Can't access element in List: "expression must be an array type"

Tags: java, list, compiler-errors

I wrote a method

```
public static final List<String> FooBar{

List<String> foobarlist = new ArrayList<String>();
 foobarlist.add("foo");
 foobarlist.add("bar");
 return foobarlist;
```

}

```
public static void man(String[] args){
   List<String> foobarlist = Foobar();
   String foo = foobarlist[0];<-- error here


}
```

I am getting this error

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is, given the error message. The compiler is correct. Go back and review the assumptions about how List objects work. Also, try *searching* - e.g. `[java] expression must be an array type`.

Comment: FYI, you should start method name with small letters.

Comment: Same idea as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504225/the-type-of-the-expression-must-be-an-array-type-but-it-resolved-to-bufferedimag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String foo = foobarlist.get(0);
```

Honestly, what you've posted here won't even compile. I would recommend that you clean that part up anyway .. Method names should begin with lowercase in Java and there should be parantheses at the end.

```
public static final List<String> foobar() {
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
    String foo = foobarlist.get(0);
```

instead of

```
    String foo = foobarlist[0];
```

[..] notation is only allowed for arrays not for Lists.

Answer (score 1):

The two issues I see:

1.
Missing parenthesis from method declaration:

```
public static final List<String> FooBar() {  // Although "foobar" / "fooBar"
                                             // would better follow naming
                                             // conventions (camelCase).
```

2.
`List` elements are accessed with [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29):

```
String foo = foobarlist.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of strings would allow you to do this:

`String foo = fooBarArray[0];`

But, since you are using a List here, you need to use this:

`String foo = foobarlist.get(0);`

This is because `List` is a container class, and an array is, well.. an array :P

Answer (score 1):

Java hasn't indexer as described in .net. You must use method get. Try this:

```
String foo = foobarlist.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As foobarlist is a List and not an array, you cannot access elements of the list by [].
You will need to use foobarlist.get(0) to acces the first element, foobarlist.get(1) to access the second element  .. and so on.
Have a look at the difference between arrays and lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487104/difference-between-list-and-array)